# Help me to prove $\operatorname{Span}(X)=F$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X \subset F$ be a subset with the following property: every linear transformation $A:E \rightarrow F$ whose image contains $X$ is surjective. Prove that $\operatorname{Span}(X)=F$.

my doubt: since $\operatorname{Im}(A)=F \supset X$, then $X\subset \operatorname{Span}(X)\subset \operatorname{Im}(A)=F \Rightarrow \operatorname{Span}(X) \subset F$. But how can I show that $F\subset \operatorname{Span}(X)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathrm{Span}(X)$ is automatically a subset of $F$ since $F$ is a vector space which contains $X$.

The other direction can be seen as follows.

Take $E = \mathrm{Span}(X)$.

Then take $A: E \rightarrow F$ to be the identity function, which we can do since $\mathrm{Span}(X) \subseteq F$.

Then $A$ is surjective, but clearly $\mathrm{im}(A) = \mathrm{Span}(X)$ so $\mathrm{Span}(X) = F$.

Comment: Good evening, Deven. Your solution proves the statement just in the case of the identity function, doesn't it?

Comment: @Walter: The statement isn't about a fixed linear transformation. The assumption made in the problem is that every linear transformation $A:E\to F$ whose image contains $X$ is surjective. In particular, we can take $A$ to be the inclusion map $\operatorname{Span}(X)\to F$, as its image contains $X$. (I say "inclusion" rather than "identity", because the latter usually refers to a function whose domain and codomain are the same set.)

Comment: @Walterr,Brad Thanks for answering for me Brad. Yes the statement says every function $E$, so we are free to choose which one we want to use.